# Differences between setuptools and pip's dependency resolution

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I've recently begun packaging my first project with SetupTools, and have mostly been successful.

Unfortunately, I've run into a confusing situation - my project depends on a single-file module which isn't available on PyPI. I've been able to configure setup.py to depend on that module easily, using the dependency_links option, and everything works... so long as I'm using setup.py to install it. If I try to use pip to install the project egg, it fails while trying to install the module, assuming that it must be a pre-made egg archive. In comparison, setup.py detects that it's a simple source file and generates an egg from that.

My aim is to have my project available on PyPI, so it's important that it be installable using just pip; so my question is... am I doing something wrong?

My understanding was that setuptools is essentially a means to an end, that end being pip and PyPI, so it seems very strange to me that the two tools should behave so differently.

The relevant part of setup.py and output from each tool follows:

```
setup(
    name='particle-fish',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='Python Boilerplate contains all the boilerplate you need to create a Python package.',
    long_description=readme + '\n\n' + history,
    author='Lachlan Pease',
    author_email='predatory.kangaroo@gmail.com',
    url='https://github.com/predakanga/particle-fish',
    packages=[
        'particle.plugins'
    ],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=['particle', 'irccrypt', 'pycrypto'],
    dependency_links=['http://www.bjrn.se/code/irccrypt/irccrypt.py#egg=irccrypt-1.0'],
    license="BSD",
    zip_safe=False,
    keywords='particle-fish',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2",
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
    ],
    test_suite='tests',
    tests_require=['pytest', 'mock', 'coverage', 'pytest-cov'],
    cmdclass = {'test': PyTest},
)
```

Output from setup.py install:

```
Installed /Users/lachlan/.virtualenvs/particle-fish/lib/python2.7/site-packages/particle_fish-0.1.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for particle-fish==0.1.0
Searching for irccrypt
Best match: irccrypt 1.0
Downloading http://www.bjrn.se/code/irccrypt/irccrypt.py#egg=irccrypt-1.0
Processing irccrypt.py
Writing /var/tmp/easy_install-svPfHF/setup.cfg
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/tmp/easy_install-svPfHF/egg-dist-tmp-Xq3OCt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding irccrypt 1.0 to easy-install.pth file
```

Output from pip install:

```
Downloading/unpacking irccrypt (from particle-fish==0.1.0)
  Downloading irccrypt.py
  Cannot unpack file /private/var/tmp/pip-mCc6La-unpack/irccrypt.py (downloaded from /Users/lachlan/.virtualenvs/particle-staging/build/irccrypt, content-type: text/plain); cannot detect archive format
Cleaning up...
Cannot determine archive format of /Users/lachlan/.virtualenvs/particle-staging/build/irccrypt
```

Comment: What versions of pip and setuptools do you have?

Comment: Pip version 1.4.1 and setuptools version 0.9.8, respectively

Comment: And upgrading to setuptools 1.1 then re-running make sdist results in the same outcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to your question:

1. What is the correct way to handle `dependency_links` specified through `setup`?
2. Why is this not being handled consistently?

---

**What is the correct way to handle `dependency_links` specified through `setup`?**

[The setuptools documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) says this for the `dependency_links` argument to the `setup` menthod:

> `dependency_links`
>   A list of strings naming URLs to be searched when satisfying dependencies. These links will be used if needed to install packages specified by `setup_requires` or `tests_require`. They will also be written into the egg’s metadata for use by tools like EasyInstall to use when installing an `.egg` file.

Now, this is pretty vague. They do mention `EasyInstall`, so we can dig into the source code there to determine how it handles `dependency_links`. Setuptools also documents the internal structure of eggs, [which includes the `dependency-links.txt` file](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/formats.html#dependency-links-txt) that corresponds to the `dependency_links` argument for `setup`. It gives us slightly more insight into what the links are actually supposed to be:

> A list of dependency URLs, one per line, as specified using the
>   `dependency_links` keyword to `setup()`.  **These may be direct
>   download URLs, or the URLs of web pages containing direct download
>   links**, and will be used by EasyInstall to find dependencies, as though
>   the user **had manually provided them via the `--find-links` command**
>   line option.  Please see the setuptools manual and EasyInstall manual
>   for more information on specifying this option, and for information on
>   how EasyInstall processes `--find-links` URLs.

*(bold emphasis mine)*

This is useful, because it points out how they are supposed to be handled, as well as what it is actually expecting. This description is slightly more useful than the `dependency_links` one, as **it specifies what "URLS to be searched" actually means**: direct download links or indexes containing them. The source code confirms that `--find-links` and `dependency_links` [are actually merged when building the egg](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/9db269094f1dd2b79591bdfd95f1e759b647acda/setuptools/dist.py?at=default#cl-368), so we can now look at the `--find-links` argument to EasyInstall for insight on what it is expecting.

> `--find-links=URLS_OR_FILENAMES, -f URLS_OR_FILENAMES`
>   Scan the specified “download pages” or directories for direct links to eggs or other distributions.

There is more detailed information there, but the general idea is that `--find-links` is **looking for eggs or archives** that contain the packages that are not found. So there's the first part of the answer to your mystery: **`dependency_links` is for pointing to full packages, not individual, unpackaged modules.**

**This sounds like how pip is processing the links** you are including, which makes sense when you read through everything. You can confirm this by looking at the tests that pip has. pip has two tests that use `dependency_links` ([1](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/517dbb94c95517caf22f0d2093732867ffee15a3/tests/data/packages/LocalEnvironMarker/setup.py), [2](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/d420497b32c11defc3f341a8df180780809a337c/tests/data/packages/LocalExtras/setup.py)), both of which are assuming that [`dependency_links` is pointing to an indexing page](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/d420497b32c11defc3f341a8df180780809a337c/tests/data/indexes/simple/simple/index.html). This seems to fall in line with the description from setuptools, where `dependency_links` is "a list of strings naming URLs to be searched".

---

So, now that we know that pip is handling this according to the specification, that leaves the second question:

**Why was this working with setuptools?**

In order to understand why this was working with setuptools, you need to understand how setuptools determines the dependencies and tries to download/install them. The [`PackageIndex.download` method](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/9db269094f1dd2b79591bdfd95f1e759b647acda/setuptools/package_index.py?at=default#cl-496) is called on any urls that are external and require the packages to be downloaded locally to install. The docstring for this function contains the answer to our question:

> If it is the URL of a .py file with an unambiguous `#egg=name-version` tag (i.e., one that escapes `-` as `_` throughout), a trivial `setup.py` is automatically created alongside the downloaded file.

This explains why setuptools was ignoring the fact that it wasn't a distribution, but pip was failing.

---

**TL;DR:** `dependency_links` should point to a package or archive containing one, not the unpackaged module. Setuptools realizes your pain and helps you out, but this is mostly undocumented. Consider repackaging the module and including it with your package if the license allows.